# Replace single line into multi line python

Tags: python

I have file.txt the contents are below

```
{"action":"validate","completed_at":"2019-12-24T15:24:40+05:30"}{"action":"validate","completed_at":"2019-12-24T15:24:42+05:30"}{"action":"validate","completed_at":"2019-12-24T15:24:45+05:30"}{"action":"validate","completed_at":"2019-12-24T15:24:48+05:30"}
```

How to convert to like below

```
{"action":"validate","completed_at":"2019-12-24T15:24:40+05:30"}
{"action":"validate","completed_at":"2019-12-24T15:24:42+05:30"}
{"action":"validate","completed_at":"2019-12-24T15:24:45+05:30"}
{"action":"validate","completed_at":"2019-12-24T15:24:48+05:30"}
```

I tried

```
with open('file.txt', w) as f:
    f.replace("}{", "}\n{")
```

Any better way is to replace?

Comment: `f.replace("}{", "}\n{")` will not work

Comment: Where do you see a `replace` method on `_io.TextIOWrapper` ?

Comment: Also, you don't need a *better* way, just a way that works ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you file is small enough you could try

```py
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    content = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(content.replace("}{", "}\n{"))
```

Comment: if large then what  :)

Comment: The solution is reading the whole content of the file, not doing a real in place replace. It would take a lot of memory!

Comment: I wrote the same almost same solution as you. can we do multi-threading on this which makes effective. `import joblib` . what is  your suggestion ? can we try on that.IF i try does it make worth

Answer (score 0):

I would not replace inplace the content, but rather read it, split it, then write it again using a simple regex `{.*?}`

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    value = f.read()

contents = re.findall('{.*?}', value)

with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for content in contents:
        f.write(content + "\n")
```